# Get resized image height with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image that I need to get the height for. I currently am using jQuery to get the height:

```
height = jQuery("#product-img-box img").attr("height");
```

The problem I face, is that I have the image resized to 88% in the css, so instead of giving me the new height, I get the height before the image was resized. Is there a way I can get the new height?

Comment: try jQuery("#product-img-box img").height();

Comment: @Raghu Thanks for the suggestion. That still returns the original height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the attribute (with `.attr()`) will always return the original inline height attribute from the DOM.

Use [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) instead (or [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) if needed).

```
height = jQuery("#product-img-box img").height();
```

---

## .height()

> **Returns:** Integer
>
> **Description:** Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: This still returns the original height

Comment: @Jordy it's advisable that you provide a http://www.jsfiddle.net with your problem

Comment: Also what's the value you're trying to get? The height in pixels or "88%"?

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/height/
Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the height of every matched element.

```
height = jQuery("#product-img-box img").height();
```

Comment: @Jordy I think we need to see your css.  This gets the adjusted height fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/F7Rrh/

Answer (score 0):

The code may also need to be wrapped into a window.resize event listener, to pass correct value when window resize. 
I had also to get the height of the element, after substituted with another when onclick, but this is another aspect that i solved by giving visibility/hidden to the wrapping element, and position absolute. The element containing image isn't anymore visible then, but will continue to resize  containing the height value and do not interfere when replaced  by the other element. If you apply css display/none to an element, the height value of the element will be 0.
Reset to visibility/visible and may position/inherit or what it was before the element when the other element (matching same dimensions) removed from dom, and the img need to reappear in place (with correct values).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var imgc = document.getElementById("w3all-flightaw-img");
var imgcheight = imgc.clientHeight;
var imgcwidth = imgc.clientWidth;
... may apply css inline to elements that need to have the same width/height, when dom ready

function reportELEMSize() {
imgcheight = document.getElementById("flightaw-img").clientHeight;
imgcwidth = document.getElementById("flightaw-img").clientWidth;
... same as above: may apply css inline to elements, when window resize
}

window.onresize = reportELEMSize; 
// OR (better, so listener not nullified by something else) use:
// window.addEventListener('resize', reportELEMSize);
});
```

it seem to me that there is no other way to resolve something like this, but waiting for some confirmation!